# PHP - Best way to count the number of things in array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I'm running a foreach loop on an array of students, that have a key ['all_user_grades']. What is the best way to count the number of As,Bs,Cs,Ds,Es and fails for each student in the array.

Here's what my array looks like:

```
[11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [All_User_Grades] => A, A, D, A, E
        )
```

Here's what my foreach looks like so far:

```
foreach($user_grades as $k => $v){
        $aug = $v['All_User_Grades'];
        $all_user_grades_arr = explode(',', $aug);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/substr_count) for this like so

```
$As = substr_count($aug, 'A');
$Bs = substr_count($aug, 'B');
//etc
```

or, just like you already did, explode and use the array for calculation

```
$all_user_grades_arr = explode(',', $aug);
$grades = array('A' => 0, 'B' => 0', ...);
foreach ($all_user_grades_arr as $val) {
    $grades[ trim($val) ]++;
}
```

The `trim()` here is necessary to get rid of unnecessary whitespaces

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function:

```
$array = array('A', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'E');
$result = array_count_values($array);

print_r($result);
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [A] => 3
    [D] => 1
    [E] => 1
)
```

Comment: Wow, PHP has so many helpful methods already implemented and so few are widely known (just like this one to me)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), i have used for single array, you change as per your requirements. See Demo  http://ideone.com/YrGfPD

```
 //PHP
 $v=array('Id'=>10,'All_User_Grades'=>'A,A,D,A,E');
 $aug = $v['All_User_Grades'];
 $all_user_grades_arr = explode(',', $aug);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r(array_count_values($all_user_grades_arr));
 echo '</pre>';

 //OUTPUT
 Success time: 0.02 memory: 24448 signal:0
 Array
 (
    [A] => 3
    [D] => 1
    [E] => 1
 )
```

Comment: @Rob177, mention not, glad  if its works for you. best of luck